# chrome.app.window.create creates two windows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

After digging around trying to figure out how to open multiple HTML files in a Chrome App, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752860/multi-window-chrome-packaged-app) as a solution. This solution opens a new window instead of it being in one window.

But for some reason, it's opening up **two windows at the same** time when I press my button hyperlink. And I do not know where in the code this is causing the problem.

So here's the important piece of the software: (script.js)

```
document.querySelector('#startButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', { "width": 400, "height": 500 });
    window.close();
});
```

And here's the button:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='index.html'" id="startButton">Let's Go!</button>
```

window.close() just closes the previous window, so it has nothing to do with that.

Screenshot: http://ibb.co/kYJQGv

My Git repo will give you what I haven't provided (under MineKart_desktop folder): https://github.com/Mr-El/MineKart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your button, you have two firing functions:

1. onclick attribute which opens the window 'index.html'
2. eventlistener to create a new window 'index.html'

Remove the onclick attribute from the button and see what happens!

Comment: @Mr.El did I answer your question adequately? If so, would you please accept my answer?

Comment: I did but I don't have enough reputation for it to show up.

Comment: I've never asked a question here before, but I think you're still able to give the green tick (mark-as-answered sort of thing). I feel you on the invisible upvotes, as a newcomer myself :)